# Pycharm code completion works, but inserts unresolved references

Tags: python, pycharm

Using PyCharm 3.0.1 Community the code completion works fine, but when I e.g. compelete to a method to one of the parents classes, the inserted method name then gets marked as an unresolved reference. What am I missing?

*Details*:

I am new to PyCharm, and test it on a (unified installed) Plone 4.3.2. The interpreter from the Installation is selected automatically, and I add the zinstance/bin/zopepy script for buildout.

I then open Products.CMFPlone-4.3.2-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/SkinsTool.py and then type

```
x = SkinsTool
```

at the bottom of the file. The code completion offers me `manage_changeProperties` (and shows PropertyManager). I select this, so that the line now says

```
x = SkinsTool.manage_changeProperties
```

The manage_changeProperties part is marked though. Hovering over the marked 'manage_changeProperties' now shows

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'manage_changeProperties' for class 'SkinsTool'
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong (e.g. with importing the project)?

**Edit**: Following vape's advice I also tried on an instance. Same problem:

Auto-complete works fine:

[image: auto-complete with manage_changeProperties]

But then the reference is unresolved:

[image: unresolved message on i]

This test was also done with 3.0.1 Professional.

**Edit 2:** The strucuture is the one of a standard plone installation: [structure.txt](http://baach.de/static/structure.txt). I have opened the topmost plone.4.3.2 folder.

Cheers,

Joerg

Comment: Have you ever solved this? Having the same problem.

Comment: There is a bug entry at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11401, which is assigned, but nothing happened yet.

Comment: Use 3.4, I think it solves the issue.

Comment: Just tried with 3.4, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the bug is fixed:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11401

The next release will hopefully contain the fix, until then I compiled my own version.

Two things to note:

1. Link (or copy) the folder 'help' from the official community release into the intellij-community/python directory.
2. comile it from that python directory using 'ant -Didea.build.number=140.1332' (I think the actual number doesn't matter)

The result is in intellij-community/out/pycharmCE/artifacts

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because there was an error when pycharm generated the skeletons for the plone library. Unless this is a bug, the only way to solve your problem is to delete the `.idea` folder inside your project. After doing so, reopen the project from the command line using `charm <your project dir>`. In case you have not made a command line tool for pycharm yet, this is how you do it:

[image]

Comment: @JoergBaach Then it’s a bug I'm afraid.